# How to Retrieve All Records from a Dojo/Store?

Tags: javascript, dojo

is there a built-in way to fetch all the records in a dojo/store (particularly a dojo/MemoryStore)? Something like:

```
store.query('*');
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple. Call the *query* method of a Store instance.

```
store.query();
```

Here is the source code of dojo/store/util/SimpleQueryEngine. Version Dojo 1.8. 
As you see, it will always return *True* if *query* is *undefined*.

```
    switch(typeof query){
    default:
        ...

    case "object": case "undefined":
        var queryObject = query;
        query = function(object){
            for(var key in queryObject){
                var required = queryObject[key];
                if(required && required.test){
                    // an object can provide a test method, which makes it work with regex
                    if(!required.test(object[key], object)){
                        return false;
                    }
                }else if(required != object[key]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
        break;
    case "string":
        ...

    case "function":
        ...
}   
function execute(array){
    // execute the whole query, first we filter
    var results = arrayUtil.filter(array, query);

    ...
    ...

    return results;
}
```

It is necessary to read the dojo source code, if documentation is confused or missing. Hope the answer will be helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the answer is extremely simple. You just access the data property directly.

```
var allData = store.data;
```

This works for MemoryStores. I don't know if it would work for stores requiring remote loading of data.